# suppress all interaction while installing apt-fast

Tags: apt, scripts, apt-fast

I want to ask whether there is any method to suppress any interaction while installing apt-fast using apt-get.

I add the ppa source and then use the next command to install apt-fast:

```
sudo apt-get -y install apt-fast
```

However, while installing, it always asks which one to wrap, apt-get or aptitude, and then the maximum number of connection. Since I want to put the installation command in my script, I want to suppress all interaction and just use the default option. As a result, I can run the script totally silence.

Any idea?

Comment: So, you want to _silently_ install software on your user's computer without telling them? Why? There's a name for software that silently installs unrequested programs, they're called malware. I assume your program is legitimate but why would you want to force your users to install something like `apt-fast`? Not to mention adding an extra ppa to the system!

Comment: The situation is that I need to install ubuntu on a lot of computer, and all of them need to be installed a lot of package via apt-get. I already write down all of the command in a script to install packages. However apt-get is slow, so I want use apt-fast.

Comment: Oh, if this is just for your computers, that's totally different. I am not at my computer now so I can't check but try `yes | apt-fast install package`; see `man yes` for more info.

Comment: My purpose is to use apt-get to install apt-fast first, so I change the command to `sudo yes | sudo apt-get -y install apt-fast`, it does not work. It still pop up a box and ask which one to wrap, apt-get or aptitude, and then the maximum number of connection.

Comment: This question has been open for a while. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: There is a bug report on the project page which includes a workaround: https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast/issues/85 (So basically pre-configuring the questions for debconf before installing)